# If Else in SQL Stored Proc on a SET Parameter

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have this Stored Procedure below. The IF/ELSE examples that I could find in MSDN and so forth do not have IF/ELSE capabilities on the "SET" Parameter.

```
BEGIN
        UPDATE c_section_status
        -- put in if else statement here to update page has changed or not.
        SET     status_ID = @status_id,
                status_date = GETDATE(),
                page_has_not_changed = @page_has_not_changed
            /*------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            -- log data to history table
            OUTPUT INSERTED.cppsa_ID,INSERTED.menuitem_ID
                ,INSERTED.status_ID,
                INSERTED.page_has_not_changed,
                INSERTED.status_date
                ,@user,GETDATE(),0
            INTO c_section_status_HIST
            /*------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        WHERE   cppsa_id = @cppsa_id
                and menuitem_id = @menuitem_id
    END
```

So I want to Set the `status_date = GETDATE()` only if the page has changed. If the `@page_has_not_changed` is equal to `1` Then I want to keep the old `status_date` and not update it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement

```
BEGIN
        UPDATE c_section_status
        -- put in if else statement here to update page has changed or not.
        SET     status_ID = @status_id,
                status_date = CASE WHEN @page_has_not_changed=1 THEN status_date  ELSE GETDATE() END,
                page_has_not_changed = @page_has_not_changed
            /*------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            -- log data to history table
            OUTPUT INSERTED.cppsa_ID,INSERTED.menuitem_ID
                ,INSERTED.status_ID,
                INSERTED.page_has_not_changed,
                INSERTED.status_date
                ,@user,GETDATE(),0
            INTO c_section_status_HIST
            /*------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        WHERE   cppsa_id = @cppsa_id
                and menuitem_id = @menuitem_id
    END
```

Notice that CASE statement comes in two flavors:

```
--Simple CASE expression:   
CASE input_expression   
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ]   
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ]   
END   
--Searched CASE expression:  
CASE  
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ]   
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ]   
END
```

- The simple CASE expression compares an expression to a set of simple
  expressions to determine the result.
- The searched CASE expression    evaluates a set of Boolean
  expressions to determine the result.

Comment: Okay. Would I not be worried that `Set status_date = status_date` wouldn't know what date to give it? since it's not an input parameter in the proc. Wouldn't i need another select statement in the Case statement to get the existing date?

Comment: @christopherclark it would store the same value it has before

Comment: Then this is the best answer, it is the least verbose. But I want to keep the old date if `@page_has_not_changed = 1`. If you make that change this will be marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

I often just do something like this in stored procs when I am trying to update a variable.

```
if (@page_has_not_changed= 0 ) 
        Begin
            --Do Something
        End
if (@page_has_not_changed = 1) 
        Begin
            --Do Something Else                 
        End
```

Comment: This is also what I looked into. Would be more verbose for large queries.

Answer (score 1):

just adding an IF condition before the UPDATE statement should work:

```
 IF @page_has_not_changed = 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE c_section_status
        SET     status_ID = @status_id,
                status_date = GETDATE(),
                page_has_not_changed = @page_has_not_changed
            /*------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            -- log data to history table
            OUTPUT INSERTED.cppsa_ID,INSERTED.menuitem_ID
                ,INSERTED.status_ID,
                INSERTED.page_has_not_changed,
                INSERTED.status_date
                ,@user,GETDATE(),0
            INTO c_section_status_HIST
            /*------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        WHERE   cppsa_id = @cppsa_id
                and menuitem_id = @menuitem_id

    END
```

Comment: I still need to make a change to @page_has_not_ changed, since the previous year could have been a 0, but the new year is 1. But yes, this appears it could work.